# How to update code::blocks to the latest version

Tags: 10.04, apt, code-blocks

I am using ubuntu 10.04. I have installed code::blocks, because I have read many good comments about it. But I have a problem: The code::blocks I installed wasn't the latest version, because I used `apt-get install` to download it. So here is my question: how can I update code::blocks to the latest version from the terminal( if it's possible ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you got two possible actions.

1. Keep updating your system , once Ubuntu have build the new code blocks , It will place it in upcoming updates . so doing regular update will give you i.e by the Ubuntu updates .
2. If you hate waiting , then you can get the packages from the codeblock site and then you can install by your own .

   If you like action 2 then here you go .

   open your terminal and type this

   ```
   wget http://space.dl.sourceforge.net/project/codeblocks.berlios/codeblocks-10.05-1-debian-i386.tar.bz2
   tar -xvf codeblocks-10.05-1-debian-i386.tar.bz2
   cd codeblocks-10.05-1-debian-i386
   ./configure
    make 
   sudo make install
   ```

hope that helps .

PS:If you faced any problems while installation then report us back . we will help you .

Hope that helps.

Comment: You could modify you answer a bit:

http://useranswer.com/answer/how-to-update-codeblocks-to-the-latest-version/

Comment: hi you can edit my answer too , if you want to improve it then you do it . @RondogiannisAristophanes